# storing Integer objects with primitive int in HashMap

Tags: integer, hashmap, primitive

HashMap uses objects as a key. If you use int primitive as key, it uses auto boxing and create integer objects for key.

is there any hashmap implementation uses primitive types as key. I dont want autoboxing. becuase hascode of integer is also value of integer.

I am trying to create integer object pool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [trove library](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/). It provides [int -> object](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TIntObjectHashMap.html) (and int -> int/float/...) hash map, directly with primitive types without autoboxing. But are you sure it is worth it? Autoboxing is fast and the jit compiler optimizes the code quite efficiently.